# Viewing data contents of generic container in cabal repl/ghci

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghci

Suppose that I have the following :

```
--Main.hs
module Main where
import Data.Vector as V
import Test

main = do
  let v = V.fromList ([1,2]::[Int])
  print (getLength v)
```

and :

```
--Test.hs
module Test where
import Data.Vector as V

getLength :: (Show a) => V.Vector a -> Int
getLength vec = let l = V.length vec in -- line 6
  l
```

I encounter the following problem when trying to print out `vec` from within `getLength` :

```
> cabal repl
> :break Test 6
> main
Stopped at Test.hs:6:25-36
_result :: Int = _
vec :: Vector a = _
> vec
<interactive>:4:1:
    No instance for (Show a) arising from a use of ‘print’
    Cannot resolve unknown runtime type ‘a’
    Use :print or :force to determine these types
    Relevant bindings include
      it :: Vector a (bound at <interactive>:4:1)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Show Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Show Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus 45 others
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I have tried to use `:force` and `:print` but neither help. Strangely when `getLength` is placed in `Main.hs`, then I have no problem printing out `vec` from within `getLength`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toList` to get to the underlying data:

```
λ :print vec
vec = (_t1::Vector a)
λ :force vec
vec = Data.Vector.Vector 0 2 _
λ :print vec
vec = Data.Vector.Vector 0 2 (_t2::GHC.Prim.Array# a)
λ let as = toList vec
λ :print as
as = (_t6::[a])
λ :force as
as = [1,2]
λ :print vec
vec = Data.Vector.Vector 0 2 (_t7::GHC.Prim.Array# Int)
λ :force vec
vec = Data.Vector.Vector 0 2 _
λ print vec
fromList [1,2]
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why I have to do this when `getLength` is in a separate file and don't have to do this when `getLength` is in the same file (i.e. in `Main.hs`)?

Comment: artella: Not really. I'm guessing when it's all compiled in a single module, the compiler does some optimizations that the debugger can detect?